# Gradle fails to import netty

Tags: java, gradle, netty

When attempting to import netty through gradle I get the error:

```
Could not find netty-tcnative-2.0.39.Final-${os.detected.classifier}.jar (io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.39.Final).
```

This is my build.gradle:

```
plugins {
    id 'java'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.jvm' version '1.4.32'
}

group 'org.example'
version '1.0-SNAPSHOT'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib"
    testImplementation 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.7.0'
    testRuntimeOnly 'org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.7.0'
    implementation "org.jsoup:jsoup:1.13.1"
    compile 'io.netty:netty-all:4.1.64.Final'
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

And here is the full error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Could not find netty-tcnative-2.0.39.Final-${os.detected.classifier}.jar (io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.39.Final).

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Exception is:
com.intellij.openapi.externalSystem.model.ExternalSystemException: Could not find netty-tcnative-2.0.39.Final-${os.detected.classifier}.jar (io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.39.Final).
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.addBuildModels(ProjectImportAction.java:346)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:127)
    at org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle.model.ProjectImportAction.execute(ProjectImportAction.java:42)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.consumer.connection.InternalBuildActionAdapter.execute(InternalBuildActionAdapter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.runAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:134)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner$ActionRunningListener.buildFinished(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:119)
    at jdk.internal.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor45.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:36)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ReflectionDispatch.dispatch(ReflectionDispatch.java:24)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:398)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$ListenerDetails.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:380)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:368)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.DefaultListenerManager$EventBroadcast$ListenerDispatch.dispatch(DefaultListenerManager.java:355)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:43)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:245)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$SingletonDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:157)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.AbstractBroadcastDispatch.dispatch(AbstractBroadcastDispatch.java:61)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:346)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.BroadcastDispatch$CompositeDispatch.dispatch(BroadcastDispatch.java:249)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:141)
    at org.gradle.internal.event.ListenerBroadcast.dispatch(ListenerBroadcast.java:37)
    at org.gradle.internal.dispatch.ProxyDispatchAdapter$DispatchingInvocationHandler.invoke(ProxyDispatchAdapter.java:94)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy19.buildFinished(Unknown Source)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
    at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.finishBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:131)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:73)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController$1.create(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.doBuild(GradleBuildController.java:67)
    at org.gradle.internal.invocation.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:56)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.runClientAction(AbstractClientProvidedBuildActionRunner.java:53)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.run(ClientProvidedPhasedActionRunner.java:47)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildOutcomeReportingBuildActionRunner.java:63)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ValidatingBuildActionRunner.run(ValidatingBuildActionRunner.java:32)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.run(FileSystemWatchingBuildActionRunner.java:77)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.run(BuildCompletionNotifyingBuildActionRunner.java:41)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$3.call(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$CallableBuildOperationWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:195)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.call(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:62)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.lambda$call$2(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.callWithUnmanagedSupport(UnmanagedBuildOperationWrapper.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.call(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:76)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:44)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.composite.internal.DefaultRootBuildState.run(DefaultRootBuildState.java:86)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:53)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:33)
    at org.gradle.internal.buildtree.BuildTreeState.run(BuildTreeState.java:49)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:32)
    at org.gradle.launcher.exec.BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(BuildTreeScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:27)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:104)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:64)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.execute(SubscribableBuildActionExecuter.java:37)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.lambda$execute$0(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:54)
    at org.gradle.internal.session.BuildSessionState.run(BuildSessionState.java:67)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:50)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.execute(SessionScopeLifecycleBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.execute(GradleThreadBuildActionExecuter.java:25)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:59)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.execute(StartParamsValidatingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:55)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.execute(SessionFailureReportingActionExecuter.java:41)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:47)
    at org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.SetupLoggingActionExecuter.execute(SetupLoggingActionExecuter.java:31)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:65)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:39)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:29)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:35)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:78)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.create(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:75)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:63)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:84)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:37)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:104)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:52)
    at org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
org.gradle.internal.resolve.ArtifactNotFoundException: Could not find netty-tcnative-2.0.39.Final-${os.detected.classifier}.jar (io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.39.Final).
    at org.gradle.internal.resolve.result.DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.notFound(DefaultBuildableArtifactResolveResult.java:28)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifactFromCache(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:345)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.CachingModuleComponentRepository$LocateInCacheRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(CachingModuleComponentRepository.java:297)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.lambda$resolveArtifact$15(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:181)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.tryResolveAndMaybeBlacklist(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:237)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.performOperationWithRetries(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:203)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository$ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepositoryAccess.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingModuleComponentRepository.java:179)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(RepositoryChainArtifactResolver.java:100)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.ComponentResolversChain$ArtifactResolverChain.resolveArtifact(ComponentResolversChain.java:129)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.ivyresolve.ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.resolveArtifact(ErrorHandlingArtifactResolver.java:46)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSupplier.calculateValue(DefaultArtifactSet.java:273)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.DefaultArtifactSet$LazyArtifactSupplier.calculateValue(DefaultArtifactSet.java:244)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer$CalculationState.lambda$attachValue$0(CalculatedValueContainer.java:216)
    at org.gradle.internal.Try.ofFailable(Try.java:39)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer$CalculationState.attachValue(CalculatedValueContainer.java:211)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer.finalizeIfNotAlready(CalculatedValueContainer.java:184)
    at org.gradle.internal.model.CalculatedValueContainer.finalizeIfNotAlready(CalculatedValueContainer.java:175)
    at org.gradle.api.internal.artifacts.ivyservice.resolveengine.artifact.ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant$DownloadArtifactFile.run(ArtifactBackedResolvedVariant.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:75)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner$3.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:153)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner.execute(DefaultBuildOperationRunner.java:68)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor$QueueWorker.execute(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:199)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runOperation(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:241)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.doRunBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:222)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.lambda$runBatch$0(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.resources.AbstractResourceLockRegistry.whileDisallowingLockChanges(AbstractResourceLockRegistry.java:70)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.whileDisallowingProjectLockChanges(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:185)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.lambda$runBatch$1(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:212)
    at org.gradle.internal.work.DefaultWorkerLeaseService.withLocks(DefaultWorkerLeaseService.java:213)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.runBatch(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:200)
    at org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationQueue$WorkerRunnable.run(DefaultBuildOperationQueue.java:172)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:64)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ManagedExecutorImpl$1.run(ManagedExecutorImpl.java:48)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1130)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:630)
    at org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ThreadFactoryImpl$ManagedThreadRunnable.run(ThreadFactoryImpl.java:56)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

This is my first time trying to import netty so I really have no clue what is causing this error to happen.

Comment: Any solution for this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Netty is a Maven project. It uses the Maven plugin [os-maven-plugin](https://github.com/trustin/os-maven-plugin) to deal platform dependencies, so Gradle could not understand what `${os.detected.classifier}` is. The solution for Gradle is using [osdetector-gradle-plugin](https://github.com/google/osdetector-gradle-plugin).

```gradle
plugins {
    id "com.google.osdetector" version "1.7.0"
}

dependencies {
    implementation('io.netty:netty-all:4.1.64.Final') {
        exclude group: 'io.netty', module: 'netty-tcnative'
    }
    implementation 'io.netty:netty-tcnative:2.0.39.Final:' + osdetector.classifier
}
```